# Why is the wedge product associative?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential

I have been reading on the wedge product (From Shutz's Geometrical Methods of Mathematical Physics) and I don't quite get why the wedge product is associative.

The book defines the wedge product of two $1$-forms as:

$$p\wedge q:=p\otimes q-q\otimes p.$$

Now writing down $p\wedge (q\wedge r)$ I get:

$$\begin{align}
p\wedge (q\wedge r) &=p\otimes (q\wedge r)-(q\wedge r)\otimes p\\
&=p\otimes (q\otimes r - r\otimes q)-(q\otimes r - r\otimes q)\otimes p\\
&=p\otimes q \otimes r - p\otimes r \otimes q - q\otimes r\otimes p + r\otimes q \otimes p.
\end{align} 
$$

The latter is different from what I've computed doing it the other way, and different from what I've found online, even more, the expression for the wedge product of three forms has six terms everywhere I've looked.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find details of this in Spivak's book "Calculus on Manifolds." on the section of "Algebraic Preliminaries".

Comment: When you wedge a one form with a two form, the formula is different.

Comment: To emphasize John's point, note that, your formula for $p \wedge (q \wedge r)$ isn't even skew-symmetric.

Comment: It's a huge pain to think of $k$-forms as being a subalgebra of a tensor algebra, precisely because you have to be annoyingly careful when you write down the wedge product. It's much cleaner to think of $k$-forms as being a *quotient* algebra of a tensor algebra, and then there's no question about why the wedge product is associative (although there is a question about why it is not zero).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think the opposite. In differential geometry $k$-forms eat tangent vectors, so they are tensors. I find the quotient viewpoint most natural algebraically, but useless in differential geometry.

Comment: @Seub for each element in the quotient of the covariant tensor algebra construction, you can easily make a well defined multilinear alternating map that way tangent vectors.

Comment: @Chris Of course. But "you can easily" --> it's even easier not to do it

Answer (score 1):

The OP said:

> I don't quite get why the wedge product is associative.

It might help to look at it in component form. Consider two vectors *(1-forms)* constructed from the 3D unit vectors:
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha&=a_1x+a_2y+a_3z\\
\beta&=b_1x+b_2y+b_3z
\end{align}
$$
To form the wedge product we can multiply $\alpha$ and $\beta$ term-by-term to obtain:
$$
\alpha\wedge\beta=a_1b_1(x\wedge x)+a_1b_2(x\wedge y)+\dots+a_3b_3(z \wedge z)
$$
However, by construction:
$$
\begin {cases}
x\wedge x=0\\
y\wedge y=0\\
z\wedge z=0
\end{cases}
\phantom{tab}\text{and}\phantom{tab}
\begin{cases}
x\wedge y=-(y\wedge x)\\
y\wedge z=-(z\wedge y)\\
z\wedge x=-(x\wedge z) 
\end{cases}
$$

So the expression reduces to the bi-vector *(2-form)*:
$$
\alpha\wedge\beta=(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)x\wedge y+(a_2b_3-c_3b_2)y\wedge z+(a_1c_3-a_3b_1)x\wedge z
$$
If we now introduce a third vector $\gamma=g_1x+g_2y+g_3z$ and follow a similar process it is not difficult to verify that the tri-vector *(3-form)* is the same whether you calculate it as $(\alpha\wedge\beta)\wedge\gamma$ or $\alpha\wedge(\beta\wedge\gamma)$:
$$(a_1b_2g_3+a_2b_3g_1+a_3b_1g_2-a_1b_3g_2-a_2b_1g_3-a_3b_2g_1)x\wedge y\wedge z
$$

---

**Note:** *when calculating tri-vectors it is important to get the correct parity (sign) of the different combinations of $x, y$ and $z$. You can derive this by counting the number of pairwise element 'swaps' required to get back to $x\wedge y\wedge z$.*

*Positive:* $(x\wedge y\wedge z),\ (z\wedge x\wedge y),\ (y\wedge z\wedge x)$

*Negative:* $(x\wedge z\wedge y),\ (y\wedge x\wedge z),\ (z\wedge y\wedge x)$